# PHP compare two arrays but all values of first array needs to be in second

Tags: php, arrays

again - sorry for the dumb explanation in the past ... i didn't get my error and this drives me crazy...

so i have two arrays - one is normal array, the other multidimensional. But maybe this doesn't matter because i explode both strings i want to compare to arrays ...

here my code:

```
<?php
$arr1 = ["folds" => '01,03,'];
if($arr1['folds'][strlen($arr1['folds'])-1] == ","){
    $arr1['folds'] = substr($arr1['folds'], 0, -1);
}
$check = explode(",", $arr1['folds']);

$arr2 = [
    ["Offer" => "Website", "folds" => '01'],
    ["Offer" => "Development", "folds" => '01,03,05,10,14,15,21,22,'],
    ["Offer" => "Testing", "folds" => '01,03,04,10,15,22'],
    ["Offer" => "Sales", "folds" => '01,03,10,22,']
];

$arr3 = [];
foreach($arr2 as $i_arr){
    if($i_arr['folds'][strlen($i_arr['folds'])-1] == ","){
        $i_arr['folds'] = substr($i_arr['folds'], 0, -1);
    }
    $tocheck = explode(",", $i_arr['folds']);
    foreach($check as $chk){
        if(in_array($chk, $tocheck)){
            $arr3[] = $i_arr;
        }
    }
}

print_r($arr3);

?>
```

so i have at least two arrays ($check and $tocheck) - $check contents search or filter values like ever you want to name it. $tocheck cames from database and got the information to be filtered.
My Code doesn't do what i want it to do - because the in_array($check[x], $tocheck[y]) checks all values in $check with all values in $tocheck - but when just one value fits it says "true".

My challenge is to only print $i_arr in $arr3 when all values in $check are also in $tocheck, not jut one...

anyone an idea?

Comment: First, these are not multi-dimensional arrays. Second, your description of `array2` is impossible; it can't contain two `folds` keys.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - Show us your code with a valid arrays as input, and the expected output. This question is unclear

Comment: yes and so array 2 is multidimensional because it has "Offer" => "Website", "folds" => "02" and another entry with "Offer" => "Development", "folds" => "02,04,09"

Comment: @kmoser i udated my whole question text and hope it is better to understand now. There is also sample code in it  now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you all - i resolved it.
Here the solution - maybe it will help someone else:

```
<?php
// Your code here!
$arr1 = ["folds" => '01,03,'];
if($arr1['folds'][strlen($arr1['folds'])-1] == ","){
    $arr1['folds'] = substr($arr1['folds'], 0, -1);
}
$check = explode(",", $arr1['folds']);

$arr2 = [
    ["Offer" => "Website", "folds" => '03'],
    ["Offer" => "Development", "folds" => '01,03,05,10,14,15,21,22,'],
    ["Offer" => "Testing", "folds" => '01,03,04,10,15,22'],
    ["Offer" => "Sales", "folds" => '01,03,10,22,']
];
$use = "no";

$arr3 = [];
foreach($arr2 as $i_arr){
    if($i_arr['folds'][strlen($i_arr['folds'])-1] == ","){
        $i_arr['folds'] = substr($i_arr['folds'], 0, -1);
    }
    $tocheck = explode(",", $i_arr['folds']);
    foreach($check as $chk){
        if(in_array($chk, $tocheck)){
            $use = "yes";
        } else {
            $use = "no";
            break;
        }
    }
    if($use == "yes"){
        $arr3[] = $i_arr;
    }
}

print_r($arr3);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through `$arr2` and check for `strpos()` of `$arr1["folds"]`:

```
<?php

$arr1 = ["folds" => '02,04'];

$arr2 = [
    ["Offer" => "Website", "folds" => '02'],
    ["Offer" => "Development", "folds" => '02,04,09']
];

$arr3 = [];
foreach($arr2 as $i_arr){
    if(isset($i_arr["folds"]) && strpos($i_arr["folds"], $arr1["folds"]) > -1){
        $arr3[] = $i_arr;
    }
}

print_r($arr3);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Offer] => Development
            [folds] => 02,04,09
        )

)
```

https://paiza.io/projects/_0nC44WHlZJpkdLOjm1Tkw

Comment: thanks for the answer but in your example array 2 is not multidimensional - so it just has "Offer" => "Development" and "folds" => "02,04,09" so this is the only thing it can return

Comment: @ManuelWeitzel I see, let me take another look

Comment: thank you, looks good on first sight, but doesn't work 100% ... as my data from second array comes out of database it could look like this:

`$arr2 = [
    ["Offer" => "Website", "folds" => '02'],
    ["Offer" => "Development", "folds" => '01,03,05,10,14,15,21,22'],
    ["Offer" => "Testing", "folds" => '01,03,04,10,15,22'],
    ["Offer" => "Sales", "folds" => '01,03,10,22']
];`

but when array 1 looks like `$arr1 = ["folds" => '01,03,10'];`

it just returns `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Offer] => Sales
            [folds] => 01,03,10,22
        ))`

Comment: @ManuelWeitzel you should add that information to the question for others to see, also try to figure out why my code works for the use case you provided, but not for these. Good luck

Comment: thanks for your answers, i am not at my goal but i am a little clearer now.

Comment: @ManuelWeitzel when in doubt, break the problem into smaller pieces. Even if it takes you an extra week, make sure you have the fundamentals down pat before you move on to more complex problems.